# how to create a chat menu button in telegrafjs

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

im creating a telegram bot using nodejs and telegrafjs
i want to know how to create this menu button i cant find anywhere in documents.

[image]

it opens up a menu like this one

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this examples](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/v4/docs/examples/keyboard-bot.js)

```
bot.command('your command', async (ctx) => {
  return await ctx.reply('this is text', Markup
    .keyboard([
      ['button 1', 'button 2'], // Row1 with 2 buttons
      ['button 3', 'button 4'], // Row2 with 2 buttons
      ['button 5', 'button 6', 'button 7'] // Row3 with 3 buttons
    ])
    .oneTime()
    .resize()
  )
})
```

Comment: example link doesn't exist anymore